# Distribution of probability with bits

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> We use 1 bit to send and the probability of this is 90%.If we send 4 bits , how will it be  the probability that
>
> a) more or equal to 2

What I did was : it was sure to use this type of distribution

$$f(x;n)=\binom{n}{x}\cdot p^x \cdot(1-p)^{(n-x)}$$

For a) I know that $\tbinom n x$ is $n!/x!(n-x)!$ so if $x=1$ and gives me $0.9$ (it is the $90\%$)  then
$P(X\geqslant 2)=1-P(X)$ so `n=4 p=2 x=2` (I dont know if is those right or wrong)

$$\begin{align}&\qquad 4!/((4-2)!2!) \cdot 2^2 \cdot (1-2)^2 \\  
    &= ( 1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4 /1\cdot2 \cdot1\cdot2  ) \cdot 4 \cdot (-1)^2
\\  &= ( 24 /4 ) *4 *1 
\\  &= 24\end{align}$$

so $1-P(X)=1-24=-23$

(I think is wrong)

> b)at least 2

For b) $P(X<2)=1-P(X)=1-0.9=0.1$

Comment: In the binomial distribution, with $n$ as the number of attempts, $x$ is the number of desired successes, and $p$ is the probability of a particular attempt as being a success, the probability of $x$ successes in $n$ attempts will be $\binom{n}{x}p^x(1-p)^{n-x}$.  For whatever reason, you used $p=2$... that is wrong.  It should have been $p=0.9$.  You should not have used $p=2$.  So... $p$ is the probability of success, and $(1-p)$ is the probability of *failure*... in your case it would have been the probability of failure as being $(1-p)=0.1$

Comment: As for *at least* style problems for these... just add up the results for each of the different $x$ that should have counted... The probability of at least two successes in four trials where each trial has chance of success being $0.9$ would be $\binom{4}{2}0.9^20.1^2+\binom{4}{3}0.9^30.1^1+\binom{4}{4}0.9^40.1^0$

Comment: @JMoravitz if I understand right,the a) exercise  is wrong and the b) is right?

Comment: @JMoravitz I have understtand everything you have wrote it.But the b) is right ?

Comment: Your attempt for (b)?  No, that is wrong too...  The phrase "at least 2" is the same as the phrase "more than or equal to 2", so I assume that you meant to write "less than 2 (*but not equal to 2*)" for (b) in which case (b) is done exactly the same as (a) with the exception that while the results for $x=2,3,4$ are all added together for the answer to (a), for (b) the results for $x=0,1$ are added together

Comment: thank you a lot @JMoravitz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$n$ is the amount of packets sent, $p$ is the probability that a packet is received okay, $X$ is the count of packets receieved okay.

Use $n=4, p=0.9$ so you have:

$$\mathsf P(X\,{=}\,x)=\binom 4x~0.9^x~0.1^{4-x}~\quad\big[x\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}\big]$$

Then $$\mathsf P(X\,{\geqslant}\, 2)= 1-\mathsf P(X\,{=}\,1)-\mathsf P(X\,{=}\,0)\\[2ex]\mathsf P(X\,{\leqslant}\,2)=1-\mathsf P(X\,{=}\,4)-\mathsf P(X\,{=}\,3)$$

Comment: Why P(X=1) and P(X=0) ? it shouldnt be X>=2 ?

Comment: Also ,P(x<=2) and you have X>2 ,I mean you have 4 and the 3

Comment: $X\geq 2$ means $X\in\{2,3,4\}$ and therefore *not* $1$ or $0$.$$\mathsf P(X\geqslant 2)=1-\mathsf P(X<2)$$The probability of an event equals one minus the probability of its complement.

Comment: got it thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ denote the number of bits that are sent.

$P(X=k) = P(k \text{ bits are sent and $4-k$ bits are not sent}) $

$\binom{n}{k}$ or "$n$ choose $k$" denotes the number of ways you can choose $k$ items from $n$ items to choose from. We'll use it here:

$P(X=k) = \binom{4}{k}(0.9)^k(0.1)^{4-k}$.

From the $4$ bits you send, we choose $k$ of them to be successes and thus $4-k$ of them are not successes. Since the probability of a success is $0.9$, and the successful sending of any two bits is independent, we multiply $0.9$ to itself $k$ times. Since the probability of a failure is $1-0.9 = 0.1$, and $k$ of our $4$ bits were successes, that means we multiply $0.1$ to itself $4-k$ times for $4-k$ failures.

Can you finish the problem from here?